# Does anyone know how to create a WPF button with style?

Tags: c#, wpf

Does anyone know how to create / add a button where has a style. I'm trying to create a button where intead of being a rectangular border.. would be a meteor border (in order that is a image), and inside would be the content (with background black).

But I'm having a hard time with the image.

Comment: if it was windows forms i would use a PictureBox with the click handling events; but i don't really know much about WPF

Comment: is it possible to post an image of what you are expecting..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would make the background an "ImageBrush", and point to your meteor picture.

Here's a link explaining ImageBrushes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904.aspx